# Animation speed decrease gradually till stop

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I am trying to decrease a number toward zero but slowly and constantly using C#.
Actually, I have to stop an animation (train) slowly not rapidly. Train will become slow gradually and then it will stop. I cant stop the train but the problem is, it become stop with little jerk
what I have tried so far

```
ANIMATION_OBJECT.animation [ClipName].speed -= Time.deltaTime * Speed * .1f;
```

to set speed gradually low but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
Time.deltaTime * Speed * .1f;
```

not equal to last time it was calculate so it will jerk. You should try to decrease with exact value and minimum at anytime like

```
ANIMATION_OBJECT.animation [ClipName].speed -= 0.05f;
```

And why you don't decrease it speed instead ?